# Search bar and search button not alligning on the same line - React, CSS, HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

The below snippet is my code for a search bar which I cannot get the search box and the button to align on the same line, can someone help me out here.

```
<Form onSubmit={submitHandler} inline>
      <Form.Control
           type='text'
           onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
           className='me-sm-2'
      ></Form.Control>

      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</Form>
```

Comment: try adding `display: flex;` on your `Form` component.

Comment: As Yong Pin mentioned above: Your `<Form>` component has `<Form.Control>` and `<button>`. Try `display: flex` on your <Form> and set `justify-content: center` `align-items: center`. See if it works.